# Regex to remove multi line comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use this regex (JS):

```
/\/\*(.*)\*\//g
```

To replace

```
/*
sdandsads
*/
```

with nothing.

But it is not working! Why? o_O

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the dot catches everything except newlines..( **if the dotall is false** )

so either use the dotall ( *as mentioned in other answers/comments this is not supported in javascript, but i will leave it here for reference* )

```
/\/\*(.*)\*\//gs
```

or add the whitespace chars `\s` in your expressions

```
/\/\*((\s|.)*?)\*\//g
```

Alan mentioned in his comment a bad performance from the answer i gave so use the following instead.. ( *which translates to everything whitespace and everything non whitespace, so everything..* )

```
/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g
```

Comment: There's no `s` (single-line) mode in JavaScript, and `(\s|.)` courts catastrophic backtracking.  The standard way to match anything-including-newlines in JS is `[\S\s]`.

Comment: @alan, any links about the `\s|.` backtracking ? would like to learn more about it..

Comment: Erik Corry explained it well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407870/javascript-regex-hangs-using-v8/2408599#2408599  For a more general discussion of catastrophic backtracking, see   http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: wow, pretty obvious once you consider that regexp has to be applied somehow, and it is not just a rule and a result  :) thanks for the links @Alan

Comment: What about `/* ... <EOF>` ?

Comment: @IvanBlack this would surely not be a comment. A compiler or an interpreter would complain about a syntax error.

Comment: For reference, dotall support was added in ECMAScript 2022.

Answer (score 7):

Two problems:

1. In javascript, there's no dotall modifier. You'll have to use a hack to allow matching newlines, such as using `[^]`.
2. You're using greedy matching. If there are multiple comments in your input, everything between them will be eaten.

Solution:

```
/\/\*[^]*?\*\//g
```

Example:

```
> '/*abc\ncde*/qqq/*iop\n\njj*/'.replace(/\/\*[^]*?\*\//g, '')
qqq
```

Comment: In truth the correct is: `/\/\*[^]*?\*+\//g`. Missing the `+` after the `\*`.
It could also be solved like this: `/\/\*.+?\*+\//gs`. The JS now supports the `s` flag in regular expressions that allows `.` to match newline characters.

Thanks so much.