# javascript multiline regexp replace

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"foo\r\nbar".replace(/(foo).+/m, "bar")
```

Hello. I can not understand why this code does not replace foo on bar

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> I can not understand why this code does not replace foo on bar

Because the dot `.` explicitly does *not* match newline characters.

This would work:

```
"foo\r\nbar".replace(/foo[\s\S]+/m, "bar")
```

because newline characters count as whitespace (`\s`).

Note that the parentheses around `foo` are superfluous, grouping has no benefits here.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know. In ruby it does by default.

Comment: `[\s\S]` is a much better workaround than `(?:.|\s)`; see Erik Corry's answer to this question for the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407870/javascript-regex-hangs-using-v8

Answer (score 25):

JavaScript does not support a dot-all modifier. A common replacement is:

```
"foo\r\nbar".replace(/(foo)[\s\S]+/, "bar")
```

`/m` makes `^` and `$` behave correctly, but has not effect on `.`.