# Cases when its better to use parantheses over square brackets in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I'm learning regular expressions on my own. So far, I seem able to achieve everything I want using square brackets (i.e `[]`), in other people's code I often see parantheses used, and I'm wondering what are some good cases / uses of paranthesis.

Can I have some examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is common error among regex beginners, and it's a serious one.  Square brackets are used to create [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), while parentheses create *groups*.  Not only do these constructs serve different purposes, there is *no overlap* in their functions.  In particular, **square brackets are not used for grouping**.  Here are some examples to illustrate:

`(abc)` matches the sequence `"abc"`
`[abc]` matches one of the characters `'a'`, `'b'`, or `'c'`.

`(abc)+` matches `abc` one or more times (`"abc"`, `"abcabc"`, etc.)
`[abc]+` matches one or more characters from the set `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` (`"a"`, `"cc"`, `"baccbcaab"`, etc.)

`(x+)` matches at least one `'x'` (`"x"`, `"xx"`, `"xxxxxxxx"`, etc.)
`[x+]` matches `'x'` or `'+'` (the letter 'x' or a literal plus sign - most regex metacharacters lose their special meanings inside character classes)

`(a-z)` matches the sequence `"a-z"` (`'a'`, hyphen, `'z'`)
`[a-z]` matches any one character in the range `a` through `z` inclusive

`(\d)` matches a digit - `\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]` (ASCII semantics) or `\p{Nd}` (Unicode semantics; "decimal digit")
`[\d]` matches a digit - unlike metacharacters, character-class shorthands retain their meanings inside "longhand" (or *enumerated*) character classes

`(\d\d)` matches two digits
`[\d\d]` matches one digit

A character class is an *atom*: it consumes exactly one character, the same as a literal character like `x` or `%` or `☺` does.  But it allows you to define a *set* of characters, and it consumes the next character if it's a member of that set.  (Specifying the same character more than once has no effect: `[abracadabra]` consumes one character from the set `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'r'}`.)

A group encloses one or more atoms, allowing them to be handled like a single atom:

- `abc?` consumes an `'a'`, followed by a `'b`', and the next character if it happens to be `'c'`.
- `(abc)?` consumes `"abc"` or nothing.

And while there are many kinds of groups, serving different purposes, none of them is equivalent to a character class.  You *can* use alternation inside a group to achieve similar results--for example, `(a|b|c)` will match the same thing as `[abc]`--but it's inherently less efficient, as well as less readable.  In fact, it can easily lead to [catastrophe](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408599/20938) explains.  If you have a choice between a character class and an alternation, you should always go with the character class.  If you need to capture the character, wrap the class in parens: `([abc])`.

Comment: Don't *all* regex metacharacters lose their meaning inside character classes, not just most of them?

Comment: Well, backslash is still the escape character, of course.  And many references say `]` retains its meaning, though now I think about it, in most flavors it only *has* special meaning if it's part of a character class, same as `-`.  So yes, I'd say "all" is just as valid as "most" in that statement, but it's more likely to provoke arguments. :D

Comment: Is `([abc])` the same as `[abc]`? If so, is there any advantage to using the first over the 2nd? Does it not make it inefficient as you mentioned using alternation is more inefficient than just using square brackets?

Comment: The parens in that case are just to capture whatever the character class matches.  For example, if you wanted to match two consecutive `'a'`s or `'b'`s (but not `"ab"` or `"ba"`), you could use `([ab])\1`.  The `([ab])` matches an `'a'` or `'b'` and stores it in capture-group #1, and the `\1` matches another of whatever's in that group.

Comment: As for the efficiency question, it was the alternation in `(a|b|c)` I was talking about, not the parens.  But that one's pretty innocuous; what really kills you is when two or more alternatives can match the same characters, like in the example I pointed to where `.` and `\s` can both match the space character (among others).  It may take a while to grok the reason for this; it did for me. :-/  In the meantime, if you find yourself able to use either a character class or an alternation and you don't see any reason to choose one over the other, trust me and go with the character class.

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses and brackets have totally different meanings in regexes.

Parentheses are used to group things, often so that the grouped text can be used later.  For instance, `(\w+)` matches one or more word characters (letters, numbers, or underscores) and saves the text for later.  How to access it depends on your programming language.

Non-capturing groups are also possible (they start with `(?`), however they tend to be used much less often.

Brackets denote a range of choices, e.g. `[abc]` matches anything with a, b, or c.  `[a-z]` matches any lowercase letter.  `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any lowercase letter, uppercase letter, or number.

They can be used together.  `^([a-z]|_)+$` matches a string that contains only lowercase letters and underscores.  That would probably be better written as `^[a-z_]+$` though.