# java regex why these two regular expressions are different

Tags: java, regex

I have a java string demonstrating a div element:

```
String source = "<div class = \"ads\">\n" +
                "\t<dl style = \"font-size:14px; color:blue;\">\n" +
                "\t\t<li>\n" +
                "\t\t\t<a href = \"http://ggicci.blog.163.com\" target = \"_blank\">Ggicci's Blog</a>\n" +
                "\t\t</li>\n" +
                "\t</dl>\n" +
                "</div>\n";
```

which in html form is:

```
<div class = "ads">
    <dl style = "font-size:14px; color:blue;">
        <li>
            <a href = "http://ggicci.blog.163.com" target = "_blank">Ggicci's Blog</a>
        </li>
    </dl>
</div>
```

And I write such a regex to extract dl element:

```
<dl[.\\s]*?>[.\\s]*?</div>
```

But it finds nothing and I modified it to be:

```
<dl(.|\\s)*?>(.|\\s)*?</div>
```

then it works. So I tested like this:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[.\\s]", "a")); --> false
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[abc\\s]", "a")); --> true
```

so why the '.' cant match 'a' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you include regexes in a post, it's a good idea to post them as you're actually using them--in this case, as Java string literals.

`"[.\\s]"` is a Java string literal representing the regex `[.\s]`; it matches a literal dot or a whitespace character.  Your regex is not trying to match a backslash or an 's', as others have said, but the crucial factor is that `.` loses its special meaning inside a character class.

`"(.|\\s)"` is a Java string literal representing the regex `(.|\s)`; it matches (*anything but a line separator character* OR *any whitespace character*).  It works as you intended, but **don't use it!**  It leaves you extremely vulnerable to [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2408599/20938).

But no worries, all you really need to do is use DOTALL mode (also known as single-line mode), which enables `.` to match anything *including* line separator characters.

```
(?s)<dl\b[^>]*>.*?</dl>
```

Comment: Thanks :) now I know more about catastrophic backtracking. it's really not easy to understand the mechanism because of my poor reading ability. but i'm trying my best ...

Answer (score 3):

Inside the square brackets, the characters are treated literaly. `[.\\s]` means "Match a dot, or a backslash or a s".

---

`(.|\\s)` is equivalent to `.`.

---

I think you really want the following regex:

```
<dl[^>]*>.*?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for above.

I would do:

```
<dl[^>]*>(.*?)</dl>
```

To match the content of `dl`

Answer (score 0):

the syntax `[.\\s]` makes no sense, because, and Daniel said, the `.` just means "a dot" in this context.

Why can't you replace your `[.\\s]` with a much simpler `.` ?

Comment: But . cant match \n, and if the content between <dl> and </dl> contains \n or \r, it will not work properly.