# Parsing differences / error in PHP7.0.3 <?php$foo

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php$selectbox->display();?>
```

which is not too much nice, but runs well on Ubuntu `PHP 7.0.3-1+deb.sury.org~vivid+1` (mod_php)

On my [uberspace](https://www.uberspace.de/)  with PHP 7.0.3 (FCGI) I get the error

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, 
   unexpected '$selectbox' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Why could this be?

Just asking out of curiosity - the fix itself is simple of course.

Comment: `space problem so it should be :-  <?php $selectbox->display();?>`

Comment: I believe OP know what is the problem but is asking why the parser behavior is different in those two cases.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69433&edit=3   and    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761351/preg-match-all-behaves-differently-on-different-servers

Comment: There must be a whitespace or newline after `<?php`. Likely in one case you have short_tags disabled (and the code is returned verbatim and not executed) and in the other case `<?` is the opening tag, so that `php` is a constant lookup and you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not due to different system. It depends on php configuration in php.ini file. In this case it depends on the `short_open` tag.

Maybe `short_open` is set to `On` in php.ini at uberspace, so after `<?` it will be considered as php starts and take the `php`(after `<?`) as constant. Therefore it will throw error for `$selectbox`. You can try with following debugging for confirm that its an actual problem of `short_open`.

1) Set `short_open` to `Off`. In php.ini change following line

```
short_open_tag = On
```

to

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

2) **Or,** Remove `php` after `<?` If you don't want to change php configuration

```
<?$selectbox->display();?>
```